# Can maven repository be added from maven extension in Maven 3.5

Tags: maven, maven-3, maven-extension

Is this code

```
project.getPluginRepositories().add(myCustomRepository);
```

executed inside `afterProjectsRead` method of a maven extension (class extending `AbstractMavenLifecycleParticipant`) supposed to work? It executes fine (no errors nor warnings) but the repo does not seem to be taken into account by Maven and build fails with "Plugin .... or one of its dependencies could not be resolved"!

If this is not possible this way, are there any other ways to dynamically add a repo from maven extension?

Comment: No it can't cause it's not intended to change the `settings.xml` based configuration...Why not changing the `settings.xml` ? What is the real problem?

Comment: This has nothing to do with `settings.xml`. It is expected to behave like if `<pluginRepositories>...</pluginRepositories>` was added to the pom.

Comment: Which is nothing different than that. The `settings.xml` defines where everything is consumed from. So usually you shouldn't change that. Can you explain more what kind of problem you are trying to resolve?

Comment: I need to be able to generate url and dynamically add custom repo based on some information that is available outside maven and may change anytime.

Comment: Why custom repos dynamically ? and changing? Sounds like it would be easier to create a template of the settings.xml and do so template processing with the informations...

Comment: Well it's a bit complicated and unusual case. The extention adds or reconfigures plugins depending on some project specific properties. Some of those plugins are available in own repositories so those need to be added as well for the plugins to discovered and downloaded. Of course I can ask my users to do that manually but they'd have to know the internal logic of the extension or add upfront all potentially needed repos. I'm trying to avoid that.

Comment: An extension is changing the plugins configuration? Sounds really weird...sorry to say that...Having repositories in different repositories is against all best practices...the plugins/artifacts are separated by their gav so no need for that...Another time. What kind of problem are you trying to solve? Why are the plugins not configured correctly in the pom file?

Comment: As I said, it's not an usual usecase. It's too complex to be explained here. You can think of it as something that simplifies POM files significantly and makes Maven more flexible. What I don't get is why an extension can add/remove/modify any plugin but can not do the same with plugin repository.

Comment: If you are saying it is not an usual use case you should explain it otherwise I can't help with best practices..The question is if there exist other/better solutions for your problem already but without knowing what your problem is I can't help...simplifying pom's often lacks from not using defaults and using corporate pom's etc. Or trying to do many things in a single module (better separation of concerns) etc. I can only speculate. It would helpful if you could make an simplified example project on github so I can take a look...

Comment: @khmarbaise I figured out a way to do it. Probably going against all Maven best practices :)  Still as I said this is unusual case and it's only a PoC. I liked the project where I use it (for only one repo for now). If you know of any better way, please let me know.

Comment: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MNG-6327

Answer (score 1):

Another way is to listen as an `EventSpy` then inject [project level settings](https://github.com/gzm55/project-settings-maven-extension), within what we can define custom repos.

For example,

in `${basedir}/.mvn/extensions.xml`

```
    <extensions xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/EXTENSIONS/1.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/EXTENSIONS/1.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/core-extensions-1.0.0.xsd">
      <extension>
        <groupId>com.github.gzm55.maven</groupId>
        <artifactId>project-settings-extension</artifactId>
        <version>0.3.5</version>
      </extension>
    </extensions>
```

in `${basedir}/.mvn/settings.xml`

```
  <settings>

    <mirrors>...</mirrors>

    <profiles>
      <profile>
        <repositories/>
      </profile>
    </profiles>

  </settings>
```

Comment: Your method works for reactor projects, but not other extensions. Im trying to get a maven-buildtime-extension to use the aopalliance artefact from my repository. Unfortunately the extension ignores the repositories defined in .m2/settings.xml because of https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MNG-6327

Comment: yes, it is a known issue (https://github.com/gzm55/project-settings-maven-extension#known-issue) as a extension. An ultimate solution is move this extension into maven core (https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MNG-6392). A work around may be put this extension jar file into $M2_HOME/lib/ext dir, then the extension will be take effect before resolving the project core-extensions.

Comment: i copied project-settings-extension-0.1.1.jar to .m2/lib/ext, but the maven-buildtime-extension still does not utilize the repository defined in the activated profile in ${base.dir}/.mvn/settings.xml

Comment: not .m2/ dir, $M2_HOME means the location where maven is installed, e.g., $M2_HOME/lib/ext --> /opt/maven/lib/ext

Comment: i see, well I cant do that

Answer (score 0):

> If this is not possible this way, are there any other ways to
>   dynamically add a repo from maven extension?

It seams this code

```
List<ArtifactRepository> pluginRepos = new LinkedList<>();
pluginRepos.addAll(project.getPluginArtifactRepositories());
pluginRepos.add(myCustomRepository);
project.setPluginArtifactRepositories(pluginRepos);
```

works. Here is an [example](https://github.com/commsen/EM/blob/0.1.x/em-maven-extension/src/main/java/com/commsen/em/maven/extension/EccentricModularityExecutionListener.java#L276) from `ExecutionListener` rather than `MavenLifecycleParticipant` but I guess it should work in `afterProjectsRead` too.

WARNING: This is probably not what Maven expects you to do and may break some plugins. For example `maven-shade-plugin` works mostly OK but breaks (and fails the build) while trying to generate reduced POM when repositories are added this way.