# How to manage CodeArtifact AUTH token on local machine

Tags: maven, aws-codeartifact

I setup a CodeArtifact maven repository and I'm able to manage artifacts dependencies during CI. I'm aslo able to retrieve an authorization token from CodeArtifact in order to fetch dependencies on local machine during development.
The problem is that the AUTH token expires after 12 hours and I'm forced to renew it.
Is there a way to setup a *settings.xml* file in *.m2* folder in order to manage CodeArtifacts maven repositories avoiding the token refresh?

Comment: Answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72649937/906519